# How to use StringTokenizer to count number of lines, tokens, # of ints, and get sum of ints?

Tags: java

Im very new to programming. This code attempts to count number of lines, tokens, # of ints, and get sum of ints in a separate file.

```java
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.BufferedReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
    
public class mcmahon_p1
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
   
        if(args.length == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a command line argument.");
        }
    
        try
        {
            java.io.BufferedReader input = new 
                java.io.BufferedReader(newjava.io.InputStreamReader(new java.io.FileInputStream(args[0])));
            String inn;
            while( (inn = input.readLine()) != null)
            {
                int lineCount++;
                inn = inn.toLowerCase(); 
                java.util.StringTokenizer st = new java.util.StringTokenizer(inn);
    
                while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                {
                    int tokenCount++;
                    String token = st.nextToken();              
         
                    try  
                    {
                        int v = integer.parseInt(token);
                        int intCount++;
                        double intSum +=v;
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
    
                    }
                }
            }    
            System.out.println(lineCount);
            System.out.println(tokenCount);
            System.out.println(intCount);
            System.out.println(intSum);
    
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
mcmahon_lab1.java:21: error: ';' expected
                int lineCount++;
                             ^
mcmahon_lab1.java:27: error: ';' expected
                    int tokenCount++;
                                  ^
mcmahon_lab1.java:33: error: ';' expected
                        int intCount++;
                                    ^
mcmahon_lab1.java:34: error: ';' expected
                        double intSum +=v;
                                     ^
mcmahon_lab1.java:34: error: not a statement
                        double intSum +=v;
```

Comment: There are a couple of typos: 1) `import java.BufferedReader;` - should be `java.io.BufferedReader`  then no need to use full class name later 2) (seems to be root cause of the bunch of the compilation errors) : `newjava.io.InputStreamReader(new java.io.FileInputStream(args[0])));` -- missing a space between `new` and `FileInputStream`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your answer correctly, your file should look like this:

```
10
34
59
62
93
```

And output of your program should be something like:

```
Line count: 5
Integer count: 5
Sum of integers: 258
```

So in this case you can use `StringTokenizer`, but I didn't understand this thing: in this format of file count of lines is equal to count of integers, but we can count the lines:

```java
int lines = 0;
int sum = 0;
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(stringToCheck, "\n");
while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
  lines++;
  sum += Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
}

System.out.println("Line count: " + lines);
System.out.println("Sum of integers: " + sum);
```

If I understood your answer wrongly, please, answer in comments :)